# Dynamically add ImagePreview with FileUploader

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**BackGround:**

I'm creating a user Profile Form where the user can add places. the places are added or removed dynamically when the user clicks on Add or Delete Button. Each Place has a `PlaceName`,`FileUploader`,an `img` tag that will show the selected file and a `Delete Button` to delete that Place.

**Goal:**
What I am trying to do is that when a user selects an image it should be displayed in the associated `img` tag .

**Current Effort:**
I have a state variable `ImagePreview` which is an array that will contain the uploaded files and `placeNameCounter` variable which indicates how many places have been added, this is used so that each `input`(file uploader) has a unique id so the first one has `customFile0` the second one would have `customFile1` and so on. There is an `onChange` listener to each of these to change the state variable `ImagePreview` so that the `img` tag can be set.

```
const GuideProfileForm = () => {
  let placeNameCounter = 0; //will convert this into state variable currently facing some issue
  const [ImagePreview, setImagePreview] = useState([]);
  const onImageChange = e => {
    setImagePreview([
      ...ImagePreview,
      {
        [e.target.id]: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
      }
    ]);
  }
};
```

the `input` and the `img` tag

```html
<input
  type="file"
  className="custom-file-input "
  id={"customFile" + placeNameCounter} //this is actually passed as props in the acutal code
  onChange={e => onImageChange(e)}
/>;
<img
  className="GuidePlaceImage"
  src={
    ImagePreview[placeNameCounter] &&
    ImagePreview[placeNameCounter]["counterFile" + placeNameCounter]
  }
/>;
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-browser-0yl5d)
(i fixed the issue , the file-uploaders wasn't working before)

Any help whatsoever would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i fixed the problem by generating a state variable which will hold the selected image associated with a specific file-uploader, whenever a place is generated

```
class NewPlace extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { ["customFile" + this.props.id]: "" }; //placeNameCounter = this.props.id
      this.ImageChange = this.ImageChange.bind(this);
    }
    ImageChange = e => {
      this.setState({
        ["customFile" + this.props.id]: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
      });
      console.log(this.state);
    };
```

and used it as

```
   <img
    className='GuidePlaceImage'
    src={this.state[["customFile" + this.props.id]]}
    style={{ height: "150px", width: "150px" }}
    />
```

so to anyone having the same issue, this is an updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-browser-0yl5d)

Answer (score 0):

I think since `setImagePreview` is async we don't have the event available within the method. A simple fix could be saving the key before hand, for example:
`const key = e.target.id;`

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-violet-owpgt

Comment: Even by doing this , it only adds an imagePreview for the first place , if you add more places by clicking on the Add button it doesn't work for them

Comment: Oh just saw the rest of the code, actually since we are directly manipulating the dom react is not able to track the changes, instead of that we should keep the places in the state as well, and use `places.map` to render them. Hope you get the idea, sorry for not checking this earlier

Comment: i do get what you are trying to say but i don't think that approach is possible since the user can add as many places as he wants so i can't keep the places as a state array and loop through them

Comment: we could do something like:
`const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
const onAddPlace = () => {  
setPlaces([...places, { }]);  
}`
  
`places.map(placeProps => <Place {...{placeProps}} />) // for rendering`

Comment: this may or may not work but i don't see how this solves the issue. the issue isn't rendering html or JSX i already did that. The issue is changing the `src` of the `img` tag to the selected file, where each FileUploader should be associated with a sepecifc `img` tag

Comment: actually I tried doing that here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-firefly-ctbnr, but it doesn't work, I guess it could be because of direct DOM manipulation

Comment: thank you for the Response @Rishabh Saxena ,but  i manged to fix it by creating a different state variable  with each place